# Start PHP Debug step by step on Form Submit

Tags: php, xdebug, form-submit

I would like to know if there may be a way to run a debug step by step when click on input button type "submit". At this time I run the debug step by step with Xdebug but the problem is that I can't finding a way to start a debugging step by step when I send a form. Can you give me some advice please?

Unfortunately, from the answers I didn't understand what I have to do. I share some configuration information I have in my Virtual Machine.
I hope it can help :

I set /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini in this mode:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9002
```

Here launch.json in VSCode (works only "Launch currently open script" but "Listen for Xdebug" and "Launch Built-in web server" don't work and i dont'know why):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9002
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=trigger",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9002,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use a browser extension to add/remove the cookie automatically, or just setup Xdebug to start a connection every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hidden form variable with the name `XDEBUG_SESSION` and as value pretty much anything.

For this to work, you need to have:

- Xdebug 3
- Set `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger`

And all the standard configuration settings for enabling Step Debugging.